# Keras Sequential: constrain weights based on other weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am new to using Tensorflow, and am trying to make a model that essentially dictates how to apportion a budget across some number of options. Hence I need to constrain the weights on each variable not only be positive but also that all of the weights add to the budget (e.g., 100% or similar).

I know I can constrain the weights individually thusly:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=[1], activation='linear',
            kernel_constraint=tf.keras.constraints.min_max_norm(min_value=0.0, max_value=1.0)))
```

But can the sum of my weights be constrained as well?

Comment: An idea would be to maybe create a custom regularization term that has a threshold in it and forces the weights to be smaller than a given budget (because of a large loss otherwise). How do you want to partition the budget? If the budget is full, does the next weight get set to zero? Or are all rescaled? If the second is what you think about, maybe normalization does something similar for you?

Comment: Ideally something like w1 + w2 + w3 = 100

Comment: why do you want weights constraints? once you have more than 1 non linear layer your constraints are useless... and if you aim to use a single layer, then don't use TF, use a library for constrained linear regression